# Union member and size of char array in c

Tags: microcontroller, c

Years ago I had a good working experience in C. Now it is rusty.
Can not find the correct way to create a union with 2 elements

```
typedef struct {
// multiple elements
}SETTINGS;

 typedef union{
       SETTINGS PROC;
       unsigned char BYTES[sizeof PROC];
 }PROCESS_SETTINGS;
```

I want to use sizeof here but can not find how anymore?
sizeof PROC reports an error.

Comment: Pure software questions like this one are more suitable for http://stackoverflow.com/, where you will likely get better answers. Particularly when it comes to "language-lawyer" stuff such as this turned out to be.

Comment: @Lundin I keep that in mind.  The solution you indicated in your  comment on Jonk was my original idea. The solution Jonk indicated works also in the MPLABX c compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C standard says:

> The **sizeof** operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type.

`PROC` is not an expression (that would require to go through an object of the union type first, e.g., `sizeof(u->PROC)`), so you have to use the type instead. And with a type, you must use parentheses:

```
typedef union {
    SETTINGS PROC;
    unsigned char BYTES[sizeof(SETTINGS)];
} PROCESS_SETTINGS;
```

Comment: Implemented already. It is ok.

Answer (score 4):

There's an odd (but useful) idiom in C that is often found. And you may find it useful here.

```
typedef union {
    short int x;
    float y;
    unsigned char z[1];
} MyUnion;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    MyUnion s;
    s.x = 1000;
    printf("%u %u %u\n", sizeof(MyUnion), s.z[0], s.z[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you don't even need to specify the actual extent of z[]. Sizing it to one meets the modern standard for syntax. Exceeding the boundary of any array at run-time is undefined behavior, but so will be using an array to index through any declaration as endian nature and padding/alignment issues are target-dependent, anyway.

---

The use of indices outside the given boundary are found in c-compiler code, libraries (malloc, for example, often uses [-1] as an array index), operating systems, and elsewhere. It's quite common, for example, to find in the use of:

```
typedef struct {
    int typecode;
    int len;
    char s[1];
} packet_t;
```

for network packets, object file records, etc. The actual allocation is done through malloc, though, to ensure that the proper size exists. It's not wrong and it's often done.

---

Since it is part of a union, it will start at the beginning. But the size of the union will be determined by the largest item and not by it.

C does require that any object have a unique address. So if the union has no other definitions inside of it, then creating an instance of the object will require space. But this is to merely meet the requirement that different instances have different addresses.

If I were simply trying to create a byte array that maps a union of object(s), I'd definitely NOT bother with a sizeof() operator, at all. I'd just write it like I did above. Saves text and saves the risk of having to edit that line if I change the name of something.

Comment: +1. Whenever I have to maintain code that makes use of unions I always feel like someone's walking over my grave.

Comment: I was aware of the situation as indicated by Jonk. I needed the sizeof information for reading from and writing to eeprom in a loop. That is also the reason for creating a Union. But maybe Wossname has a better idea.

Comment: @Decapod The union is only a declaration. Not a definition. And you will need to use sizeof() as part of a run-time bit of code, no matter what else you do. So there is no change in that respect, at all. It's just a simpler declaration, is all. And better, IMHO. Of course you will need to do a run-time loop and that loop will need to know the size. But the declaration does NOT need to know the size (that's computed anyway at compile-time.) The simpler declaration is better, I think. Just an opinion, though.

Comment: @Jonk. I know the union is only a declaration. I have implemented my code the way you suggest and removed also the sizeof in the declaration of the union. The only place where I use the sizeof  is in the loop.

Comment: @Decapod That's how it should be, I think. The additional sizeof() there really doesn't do anything useful. Worse, if you accidentally make it a larger value than needed by the union's other members, you'd have an unintended side-effect making the union larger than needed. Of course, if you actually *wanted* to do that, then it might be a way of making the union always a fixed, standardized size no matter what it contained, I suppose. (There always seems to be two edges to every sword, I guess.) [I've been using C since 1978 when I first worked on the Unix v6 kernel. Long time, now.]

Comment: @Jonk. I have been using C also a long time. But did not programm the last 20 years. Now retired just for fun.

Comment: @Decapod I can't retire and wouldn't want to, anyway. My wife and I run three different businesses and this is probably the only thing I do for away-time. Every other moment is occupied with some task supporting some project or another. Luckily, I *love* everything I do for pay and would do it for free, otherwise. So I'm very lucky that way, I suppose.

Comment: Sorry but this code isn't valid C. A union may not contain a flexible array member. If you somehow managed to get this to compile, which I doubt, you are using a non-standard compiler. You probably meant to do `typedef struct { short int x; float y; } stuff_t;` and then `typedef union {
  stuff_t; uint8_t bytes [sizeof(stuff_t)]; } union_t;`.

Comment: @Lundin If you want to make it standard, just use z[1] rather than z[] as I illustrated. Then it fits the standard, fine. I think the old z[0] is deprecated. But z[1] is not.

Comment: @jonk No. `z[1]` is known as the crappy old "struct hack" trick from the dark ages and shouldn't be used, because it invokes poorly-defined behavior. It causes issues with padding bytes (that have indeterminate values), alignment and so on. Instead use standard C flexible array members, that only work in structs not unions. `z[0]` was never valid C but gcc had a non-standard extension that was used in the 90s before the C language was fixed to support flexible array members, in the year 1999.

Comment: @Lundin z[1] is just fine. Still legal, as well. z[0] was valid C and in fact is specifically mentioned in some of the more recent standard subcommittee documents -- for example, in regards to the struct idiom. That use is deprecated. But z[1] is legal. Still legal and not deprecated. However, one still needs to deal with packing/alignment issues (and endian nature), which vary machine to machine.

Comment: @jonk Accessing an array out-of-bounds is undefined behavior, as is relying on the indeterminate values of struct padding bytes. So you cannot use an array of size 1 neither to describe trailing data in a a struct, nor as a way to get a byte array in a union. You would get aliasing problems too - given `union { int x; char y[1]; }` the compiler is free to assume that `x` is never changed if you write `y[1]=1;` and can therefore optimize away the whole code.

Comment: With `z[0]` I mean _an array with zero size_ which has never been valid C, but is a gcc non-standard extension. It is explicitly forbidden as per ISO 9899:2011 6.7.6.2/1 Array declarators: "If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero." Period.

Comment: @Lundin Use z[1] to avoid the newer "difficulty." And the whole idea of using an array to map the object is inherently undefined. But undefined doesn't mean illegal. And the as-if rule always applies. That's not new. Putting words in my mouth doesn't improve the argument. I'll update my post to reflect the more modern standard, though.

Comment: @jonk Type punning through unions in C is perfectly legal. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning. It has to be type punning with a character type though (byte), otherwise I suppose there might be various aliasing concerns.

Comment: @Lundin Uses of array indices, such as -1 (or numbers beyond the compile-time constants in their declarations) is, and always must be, supported for the correct operation of certain kinds of code. I'll let you have the last word and leave it there. This is my last comment to you on this topic. This is moving onto opinion that has already long been debated in subcommittee. I'm not going to budge because I know about the specific applications that require the support and the compilers do have to support it.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Always use parenthesis after `sizeof` and it will work.

This is because of the peculiar syntax of the `sizeof` operator, C11 6.5.3:

> 6.5.3 Unary operators
>   Syntax
>   /--/
>   **sizeof** *unary-expression*
>   **sizeof** *( type-name )*

As we can see it comes in two forms, one form that can be used for compile-time expressions and does not need parenthesis, and another form that can be used for types, which does need parenthesis.

Meaning:

```
sizeof 1;     // ok, it's an expression
sizeof int;   // syntax error, it's a type
sizeof (int); // ok
```

Now, as it turns out, any expression can contain a parenthesis, which is an operator with the highest precedence:

```
sizeof (1);   // ok, here the parenthesis is an operator of its own not part of sizeof
sizeof (int); // ok, here the parenthesis is part of the sizeof operator syntax
```

So one can always write a parenthesis after `sizeof` and it will cover both cases.